# How to check whether the OTP sent is expired or not and verify OTP for forgot/ reset password in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, twilio-api, forgot-password, reset-password

I am developing an API for reset/ forgot password. I have created an API for send otp to registered user only. In this, I am storing generated OTP in database too.

Below is my SenOTP model:

```
public class SendOTP {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long sendotpid;
    private int otp;
    private String phone;
    private static final long OTP_VALID_DURATION = 5 * 60 * 1000;   // 5 minutes
    @Column(name="otp_Requested_Time")
    private Date otpRequestedTime;
    public boolean isOTPRequired() {
        if(this.getOtp() == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        long currentTimeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long otpRequestedTimeMillis = this.otpRequestedTime.getTime();
        if(otpRequestedTimeMillis + OTP_VALID_DURATION < currentTimeInMillis) {
            // otp expires
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Below is send otp to regsitered phone number API:

```
public int getOTP() {
    Random r = new Random();
    int min = 1000;
    int max = 9999;
    int uid = r.nextInt(max-min) + min;
    return uid;
}
public ResponseEntity<?> sendotptoregisteredphone(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam("phone") String phone) {
      CustomResponse = ResponseFactory.getResponse(request);
      phone = phone.replace(" 1", "").replace("NA", "").replace(" 1NA", "").replace(",", "").replace("-", "").replace("(", "").replace(")", "").replace(" ", "");
                  User registeredUser = userDao.findByPhoneAndPhoneverify(phone,1);
                  if(registeredUser != null) {
                      if(phone.equals(registeredUser.getPhone())) {
                          int otp = getOTP();
                            SendOTP s = new SendOTP();
                            s.setOtp(otp);
                            s.setPhone(phone);
                            s.setOtpRequestedTime(new Date());
                            SendOTP sotp = sendOtpDao.save(s);
                            
                            // Here is my Twilio implementation to send message to entered phone number
                            CustomResponse.setResponse(sotp);
                            CustomResponse.setStatus(CustomStatus.OK);  
                            CustomResponse.setStatusCode(CustomStatus.OK_CODE);
                            CustomResponse.setResponseMessage(CustomStatus.SuccessMsg);
                      }
                  }else {
                      CustomResponse.setResponse("Sorry ! Phone number is not registered with us.");
                      CustomResponse.setStatus(CustomStatus.Error);
                      CustomResponse.setStatusCode(CustomStatus.Error_CODE);
                  }
        return new ResponseEntity<ResponseDao>(CustomResponse, HttpStatus.OK); 
      }
```

Below API is to verify entered OTP:

```
public ResponseEntity<?> verifyotp(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam("otp") String otp) {
      CustomResponse = ResponseFactory.getResponse(request);
      int flag = checkapikey(apikey);
      SendOTP otpByUser;
          try {
              if(otp != null || otp != "" || otp.equalsIgnoreCase("NA")) {
                  int otpValue = Integer.parseInt(otp);
                  otpByUser = sendOtpDao.findByOtp(otpValue);
                  // What next, I am bit confuse here.
              }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                CustomResponse.setResponse("Error occurred! please try again");
                CustomResponse.setStatus(CustomStatus.Error);   
                CustomResponse.setStatusCode(CustomStatus.Error_CODE);
            }
        return new ResponseEntity<ResponseDao>(CustomResponse, HttpStatus.OK); 
      }
```

Now, next I want to verify or validate OTP that user will enter and check whether the OTP is expired or not. If OTP is not expired then forgot/reset password API should work.
Please suggest me any solution or answer.

Comment: You save the requestedTime, compare that to the current time minus e.g. 5 minutes to check if more than 5 minutes have passed or not.

Comment: In verify OTP code. right?

Comment: @Rakhi It seems your `isOTPRequired()` method is already having the logic to check the expiration time..  Why don't you call that method after getting user OTP and if true then compare the user OTP with the saved OTP?

Comment: Okay. Got it. I am doing that.